# jQuery, selector matches unset class?

Tags: jquery, click, selector, behavior, removeclass

I'm having an issue with a classed bases switch on some jQuery code and I want to know if I do something wrong or ran into a bug (probably the first though).

See this exampe:

```
// Expecting only one run
// Instead it keeps triggering
$('.switch').click(function () {
    // Show message with active classes
    var classes = $(this).attr('class');
    alert('Classes: '+classes);

    // Remove class, it shouldn't trigger again?
    $(this).removeClass('switch')
})
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/aK6FB/2/)

I have a simple HTML tag with a class. A jQuery script matches the class and binds it to a click event. If the event is triggered it's removes the class and thefore, I'm expecting it not to match a second time (in other words: it should only be executed once).

However, the code gets executed everytime. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: The event attaches itself to the element (in the way you are using it now) so no matter what happens to that element as long as it's still *alive* the event is still available to trigger.

Comment: `$('.switch').click(...)` binds a handler to the _element_. Changing a property of the element doesn't change the handlers that are bound to that element.

Answer (score 0):

use event delegation for dom changes:

```
$(document).on('click','.switch',function () {
  var classes = $(this).attr('class');
  alert('Classes: '+classes);
  $(this).toggleClass('switch')
});
```

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aK6FB/8/)**

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The one() solution also looks nice but doesn't seem to be usable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```
$('.switch').one('click',function () {
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wfPmh/)

Comment: Thanks, I had to go with Milind Anantwar's solution but this is also  usefull.

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur Glad you found the solution .